# Redux not triggering re-render even-though I am not mutating my state in my reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm having some difficulty with React Redux. It's related to components not re-rendering after a state change. Every question that is asked online refers to it probably being that you are mutating the state, however, I am almost 100% sure that I am not making that mistake. After having tried multiple approaches I just don't know what is going wrong.

Here is my original reducer code:

```
import * as actionTypes from '../actions/actionTypes';
import { updateObject } from '../utility';


const initialState = {
    jwsToken: null,
    accessToken: null,
};


const updateTokens = (state, action) => {
    return updateObject(state, {jwsToken: action.jwsToken, accessToken: action.accessToken})
};

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case actionTypes.UPDATE_TOKENS: return updateTokens(state, action);
        default:
            return state;
    };
};


export default reducer
```

I'm using a utility function (updateObject) to make a copy of my object that I want to return in the reducer. It looks like this:

```
export const updateObject = (oldObject, updatedProperties) => {
    return {
        ...oldObject,
        ...updatedProperties
    };
};
```

I also tried it without the updateObject utility function and using Object.assign():

```
const updateTokens = (state, action) => {
    return Object.assign({}, state, {
            jwsToken: action.jwsToken,
            accessToken: action.accessToken,
        })
};
```

I fear that I'm doing something super stupid, but I've spent too much time on this now not to ask. Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Edit
Here is my component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import * as actions from "../../store/actions/index";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

class Calendar extends Component {

    componentDidMount () {
        if (this.props.accessToken) {
           this.onGetEvents()
        }
    }

    onGetEvents = () => {
        this.props.getEventsSelectedMonth(this.props.selectedMonth, 
        this.props.accessToken)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            //JSX here
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        accessToken: state.accessToken,
        selectedMonth: state.selectedMonth
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        getEventsSelectedMonth: (selectedMonth, accessToken) => 
        dispatch(actions.getEventsSelectedMonth(selectedMonth, accessToken))
    };
};


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps) (Calendar);
```

Comment: show the component?

Comment: Of course, my bad, I added my component in an edit.

Comment: this.props.getEventsSelectedMonth -> what does getEventsSelectedMonth changes? What is it you are rendering? did u try console.log(this.props) to make sure props are updated?

Comment: getEventsSelectedMonth is an redux action that performs an axios.get() to the Google Calendar API and then is sent to the reducer to update the state. It functions, I've checked it. When I console.log(this.props.accessToken in my component, it returns null, so it hasn't been filled yet. Even though when looking in the Redux Dev Tools the reducer did run and the accessToken is no longer null.

Comment: where did you place the `console.log`? Do you happen to have any other hooks that prevent rerender like `shouldComponentUpdate`?
Try using `componentDidUpdate` to check the value... maybe the Axios request isn't done by the time componentDidMount gets called.

Comment: Changing componentDidMount into ComponentDidUpdate does make my getEventsSelectedMonth run! However, it enters an infinity loop, why is that happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid the infinite loop you can make sure to call the required function only when the value is changed:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if (prevProps.accesstoken !== this.props.accessToken) {
     this.onGetEvents()
  }
}
```

The infinite loop happens as without the check we would continuously change the state on every update(which occurs because of the state change).

From your comments, I'm assuming you're getting different access tokens every time so maybe you just want to call `onGetEvents` when you get an accessToken for the first time.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  // only call when the previous token is falsy and there's a new truthy token 
  if (!prevProps.accesstoken && this.props.accessToken) {
     this.onGetEvents()
  }
}
```

Comment: It's still entering an infinite loop, which is really weird because I'm console.logging both prevProps.accessToken and this.props.accessToken and they are clearly the same.

Comment: check if you're entering inside the if block

Comment: Do you mean if this.onGetEvents() runs? Yes, it does, on infinite.

Comment: Yes, but is it running because of the call inside `componentDidUpdate` or something else. Maybe you're getting different access tokens every time so perhaps the check should be modified.

Comment: Ok, so this is what I got: I copied both the prevProps.accessToken and this.props.accessToken (both strings) that were printed on the console by my console.log(). I copied it into my IDE (Visual Studio Code) where I could check if highlighting/selecting one would select the other... and it doesn't. They look the same, yet they are not, how is that?

Comment: lol, access tokens have a lot of characters maybe one/few of them are different. Add them to the question.

Comment: The first piece of code works! All of a sudden, I still don't really understand what went wrong, but it works now